# Function that represents growth with specific specs

Tags: functions, logarithms

I'm looking for a function that represents growth based on the following specs:

In a range of 365 days  the function may grow from (almost) zero to a maximum of 1. It should have some kind of logarithmic shape, because the growth in the first 30 days should happen quite fast (~ 50%).

Anyone an idea how to achieve that?
Thanks in advance,

Hitch

EDIT: Made a major mistake: the range is 365 days, not 100!

That's how it should look like:
[image]

Comment: Could you put a few numbers ?

Comment: actually not - it's not an empirical case, rather a theoretical assumption. I just want an approximate progress that more or less fits my specifications.

Comment: what I have is a timeline from t=1 to t=100 (in days) - and in that period the function shall grow in the way I noted above

Answer (score 0):

For passing through $(100,a)$ and $(30, 0.5a)$, I have a function using $\sin$:

$$f(x)=\sin\left(45\cdot \sin \left(x \right) \right).$$

Comment: well maybe I inarticulated my concern, but this is not what I'm looking for, sorry. This function oscillates...

Comment: can you please draw a graph for your function?

Comment: maybe you could go for `f(x)=(ax+b)^1/2` or something like that

Comment: Sorry, but i dont think you get the point... The growth shall take place in the interval [0;1] with the shape I suggested in my drawing.